# Inverted parenthesis in rtl language flutter

Tags: flutter, direction

inverted parenthesis are being displayed by flutter in rtl language such as urdu.

[image: Inverted patenthesis]

Till now i have tried `textDirection: TextDirection.rtl`,`textDirection: TextDirection.ltr`, `Directionality widget`, tried string with `\u200E`... none of it worked. do anyone have a solution?